# Pandas custom aggfunc returns string is limiting the amount of characters

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to do a pivot table from a django queryset.
Its working perfect, and instead of an aggregation math operation I am returning a string.

Things were working perfect, until I start returning an html string. Here is whats happening now: pandas starts limiting my string!

Here are the example code and its output:

```
def agg30(series):
    ret=''
    for i in range(0,30):
        ret += "%d"%i
    return ret

def agg29(series):
    ret=''
    for i in range(0,29):
        ret += "%d"%i
    return ret
```

This is my view that generates the panda pivot:

```
pd_html=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['title','day'],columns=['bb'],values=['id'],fill_value='',  aggfunc=agg30)
pd_html= pd_html.to_html(classes =['table'],border=0,
index_names =True,
escape=False)
```

If I use agg30, my output is:

> 0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627...

If I use agg29, my ouput is:

> 012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728

I need to be able to return more characters.... anyone has any idea on how to do so?

Comment: have you tried changing pandas display options? eg. `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)`

Comment: Perfect! It worked like a charm. Please post as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.set_option`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html). For example:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)
```